# syntax highlighting for python not working in vim for Windows

Tags: windows-7, vim, syntax

I want to use [Pretty-Python-Vim](https://github.com/sentientmachine/Pretty-Vim-Python) in windows and have installed the necessary packages an placed .vim directory as described in the website. However even after doing the necessary changes in my vimrc file, I'm not able to get the proper syntax for my python file. I also added `syntax on` in my `D:\vim\_vimrc` file but that didn't help either.  Image of how python file currently looks like is below[image]
Any idea how can I get the correct syntax to work ?